# If I go to a store and the cashier asks "有會買嗎?" what does that mean?

Tags: meaning, usage

For example, if a cashier rings me up and says "這樣一共是五百元, 有會買嗎?" What does the "有會買嗎" mean and how would I respond? Thank you.

Comment: 有會/Yǒu huì/買嗎? doesn't sound right to me. It should be 要/Yào/買嗎?

Comment: @TangHo That is the sentence I read. Maybe it sounds odd because it is from Taiwan?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it's not "有會員嗎"(員 vs. 買)? It certainly sounds like it, the cashier is asking if you have a membership at the store.

Comment: Yeah, If you were a member, you'd get discount or reward point or something.